# If electrons absorb photons to reach higher energy levels in Bohr's atom, why do they have lesser kinetic energy?

Tags: electrons, atomic-structure

In Bohr's atomic model, an electron can jump to a higher energy level by absorbing a photon with energy equal to the difference in energy between 2 energy levels. This should mean that the electron now has more kinetic energy than it had in the previous orbit. But the velocity of an electron in an orbit is inversely proportional to the orbit number (the formula for velocity given as $\frac{2\pi ke^2}{h} \times \frac{Z}{n}$), which means that the electron has lower kinetic energy.

So my question here is, if the electron absorbs a photon to go into a higher energy level, why does it have lesser kinetic energy than it had before?

Comment: Beside that you already know that Bohr model is just a passage, the same can be asked about a satellite. This is how mechanics works. The energy input goes into kinetic and potential energy. You said it before asking. When you rise a weight, its potential energy rises, independently of its motion.

Comment: @Alchimista oh so it gets converted to potential energy, got it, thank you :)

Comment: By the way, Bohr's atomic model is not very accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bohr model, in its initial form, is still based on the circular motion around a central object acting by a quadratic force $F = \frac{k}{ r^2}$.

In such a system, objects with higher total energy have lower kinetic energy, as the increase of their potential energy is 2 times greater than the loss of the kinetic energy.

$$E_\mathrm{tot} = E_\mathrm{pot} + E_\mathrm{kin}$$

$$E_\mathrm{pot} = - 2 \cdot E_\mathrm{kin}$$

so

$$E_\mathrm{tot} = - E_\mathrm{kin}$$

this is also the reason, why $$v_\mathrm{escape} = \sqrt{2} \cdot v_\mathrm{circular}$$

If Earth had been orbiting Sun at the distance Venus has, it would have  moved faster than now, with the total ( kinetic + potential ) energy lower. Similarly, satellites need to gain energy to reach a higher orbit with a lower speed.